# jquery Tiny Colorpicker event change

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange, jquery-events, color-picker

How to code **on change** event in [Tiny Colorpicker](http://www.dematte.at/tinyColorPicker/)

please help me !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[colorPicker github](https://github.com/PitPik/colorPicker)

```js
$(function() {
  $('#colorA').colorPicker({
    renderCallback: function($elm, toggled) {
      var id = $elm.attr('id');
      if ($elm.text) {
        $('#getColor').text(id + ': ' + $elm.text).css('background-color', $elm.text);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.dematte.at/tinyColorPicker/jqColorPicker.min.js"></script>

<div id="getColor">Color</div>
<input type="text" value="#123456" id="colorA">
```

**Disclaimer** [original author work](https://fiddle.jshell.net/onigetoc/otyk5fkq/) in this link

Comment: nice. thank you so much ! but can you explain for me about: `var id = $elm.attr('id');`

Comment: getting itself i.e color picker input .here it id `colorA` element